# Google maps perfomance with polylines and markers

Tags: silverlight, google-maps

We are on decision point - which technology will be used for our highly loaded flight deals map. 
There is simple test - http://buruki.com/gmap but if i choose London or Moscow( they have **~200-300 flights destinations**) most of browsers( firefox 3.5 and IE for sure :-) ) are extremely slow.
Now there are simple markers and simple polylines, MarkerManager or other things are not use.

I would like to ask gmap experts - is it possible to have almost immediate response time with ~200-300 polylines and markers on map. If yes - any live examples from existing projects.

PS we already have **silverlight**( http://buruki.com/map ) implementation, it has great speed and great disadvantages :-( - plugin is required, linux users are out of bossiness. Is it possible to achieve same speed(or close) as silverlight has with gmaps?

Answer (score 1):

Answer : yes it is possible not only for 200-300 but also you can add more then 500. I worked on one of the airline site same like your and i attached different markers and polyline more then 200 within a 5 milisecond with google map V3. I made an javascript file for that and an array for whole data with lat long after that i used for loop for placing  a marker images with lat long (which data is comes from an array). Till now no any bug appear in that and every thing with heavy data working fine. thanks