# Multiple polylines overlapped on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to show multiple flight routes on google map. I used polyline with geodesic for that and that is working fine but the problem is when more then two flights going through same route then polyline overlapped by another polyline. Can we solve this by changing curve angle or can we little bit separate from each other.

Comment: What is your question?  How to draw two geodesic polylines given three points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I am working on this url I think it will work and it is best way to solve this question problem: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-headings

Comment: This is the best document for learn polyline/geodesc lines for showing curve routes and very easily can implement

Comment: polyline overlapped is still an issue

Comment: what we will do, if more than 2 polylines overlap on complete route, I am suffering with this condition I tried a lot with stroke weight and its color but I am unable to display separate to all polylines. So I am thinking about can we change curve angel like add or less some degree then route can be more curvy and we could see all in separate form. I am google for this but still with no great result. Can any one have an idea how to do this